# backdrop-filter blur does not overflay on all elements underneath

Tags: html, css, filter, z-index

I'm trying hard to understand why `backdrop-filter: blur()` used in an overlay will not overlay and apply to all elements it is on top of.

In the screenshot below - the overlay works on a div - but not on the text... What are the conditions that would make the backdrop overlay over some elements and not others?

Here are the overlay styles:

```
.Nav-module_backdropOverlay__3EPp5 {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.1);
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    outline: pointer;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    visibility: visible;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: -10; // this z-index is set to position behind the top-nav bar - but above the main content.
// the parent z-index is 999;
    -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(8px);
    backdrop-filter: blur(8px);
    cursor: pointer;
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
}
```

[image: The overlay works on top of the bullet list - but not the text]

I can verify that the overlay is stacked on top of all other elements by testing with a different background color and the overlay indeed is working properly
[image: Changed background to red]

Comment: Are you sure it is probleme of backdrop-filter and not positionning ? Change the background-color to be sure. If it is a positionning problem the HTML code would help

Comment: @CedricCholley That's a good callout- I changed the background color to red and i can verify that the element with the backdrop is overlayed on top of all other elements

Comment: Can you please post HTML code so we may reproduce the problem